# Cohomology theories for algebraic varieties over number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives

There is a standard line which is repeated by anyone writing/talking about motives and cohomology of algebraic varieties over number fields: namely, there are many such cohomologies and then the following list is given: Betti, De Rham, Etale and Crystalline. It seems like everyone gives the same list. This leads to the following:

Question: What other examples of cohomology theories for algebraic varieties over number field should one keep in mind? To put it slightly differently, when discussing motives, we have the Betti, de Rham, etale and crystalline realisations. Are there other realisations one should think about?

For instance, do Scholze and co-authors construct a new cohomology theory which should be added to the above list? E.g. can one talk about the "prismatic realisation" of a motive?

Comment: They do and not just one. Off the top of my head, you have $\mathbb A_{\mathrm{inf}}$, prismatic, and $q$-de Rham cohomology (you may need to base change to an appropriate $p$-adic ring to define them).

Comment: Yes, my impression was that these are defined over $p$-adic rings, but then a more knowledgeable person told me that there are also candidates over rational numbers.

Comment: There is also Deligne cohomology and Beilinson's absolute Hodge cohomology, and on the $p$-adic side, Besser's rigid syntomic cohomology, Besser's finite polynomial cohomology, and many others.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Are these for algebraic varieties over number field?

Comment: You can define them for varieties over the complex numbers, respectively over the $p$-adics. For an algebraic variety over number field, you just base change to these fields (exactly like Betti cohomology is defined for complex varieties, not just varieties over number fields).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I wouldn't say that "absolute" theories like syntomic 
or Deligne count as "realisations" of a motive (since one of the formulations of the question was "which realisations should one think about"). These theories  don't satisfy the Kunneth formula, for instance. (Morally they are realisations of Ext-groups in the hypothetical category of mixed motives, not of objects in that category.)

Comment: Yes, I believe that a "realization" is something that possesses a collection of properties that can be wrong for something that one calls "cohomology".

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Right, I was misled by the beginning of the question. Thanks for pointing it out. So a definition of "realisation" could be a $\otimes$-functor (not just additive), from the (hypothetical) tannakian category of mixed motives into some tannakian category. For "categories of realisations" (substitutes of the category of mixed motives), one needs to take sufficiently many realisations in order for this $\otimes$-functor to be fully faithful. E.g. Grothendieck's period conjecture implies that the $\otimes$-functor given by Betti + de Rham + period isomorphism is fully faithful.